# I have a group of radio button in each row of the gridview. Base on the user selection of the radio button, I would like to update the database

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a group of radio button in each row of the gridview.  Base on the user selection of the radio button, I would like to update the database, when user click the Submit Button on the page. How do I reference those radio button in the code page?
source code

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvActList" runat="server" Font-Size="Smaller" Width="100%" CssClass="tableStyle"
    EmptyDataText="No Data Found" AllowPaging="false"
    CellPadding="4" AutoGenerateColumns="False" autopostback="true">
    <FooterStyle Font-Bold="True" CssClass="tablefooter" />
    <RowStyle CssClass="tableRow1" />
    <SelectedRowStyle Font-Bold="True" CssClass="tableRowHighlight" />
    <HeaderStyle Font-Bold="True" CssClass="tableHeader" Font-Size="9px" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="TM Activity Code" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
            <ItemStyle Width="5%" HorizontalAlign="Left"></ItemStyle>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lbl_Activity_Code" runat="server" Visible="true" Text='<%# Bind("ACTIVITY_CODE") %>'></asp:Label></ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Description" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
            <ItemStyle Width="19%" HorizontalAlign="Left"></ItemStyle>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lbl_ACTDESC" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ACTIVITY_DESC") %>' Visible="true"></asp:Label></ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="User Details" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
            <ItemStyle Width="5%"></ItemStyle>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lbl_User_Details" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CREATED_BY") %>' Visible="true"></asp:Label></ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Type" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
            <ItemStyle Width="5%"></ItemStyle>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lbl_PROMO_TYPE" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("PROMO_TYPE") %>' Visible="true"></asp:Label></ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Category" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
            <ItemStyle Width="5%"></ItemStyle>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblCatgDescription" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CATEGORY_CODE") %>'
                    Visible="true"></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Date Range" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
            <ItemStyle Width="5%"></ItemStyle>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblACTIVEFROM" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ACTIVE_FROM") %>' Visible="true"></asp:Label>&#160; To &#160;
                <asp:Label ID="lblACTIVETO" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ACTIVE_TO") %>' Visible="true"></asp:Label></ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Activity Type" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
            <ItemStyle Width="5%"></ItemStyle>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lbl_Actvity_Type" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ACTIVITY_TYPE") %>' Visible="true"></asp:Label></ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Current Status" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
            <ItemStyle Width="5%"></ItemStyle>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lbl_Current_Status" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("status") %>' Visible="true"></asp:Label></ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="View Details" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <itemstyle width="5%" />
                <asp:LinkButton CssClass="l_link" Text="View" ID="lnkView" runat="server" ToolTip="View" /></ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblCap" Text="Confirm" runat="server"></asp:Label></HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></ItemStyle>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <itemstyle width="1%" font-size="2px" horizontalalign="Center" />
                <table style="text-align: Center; vertical-align: text-top;">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 98%;">
                            <asp:RadioButton ID="rdYes" runat="server" Text="Yes" GroupName="CH"></asp:RadioButton></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 98%;">
                            <asp:RadioButton ID="rdNo" runat="server" Text="No" GroupName="CH"></asp:RadioButton></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 98%;">
                            <asp:RadioButton ID="rdNone" runat="server" Text="None" GroupName="CH"></asp:RadioButton></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
    <EditRowStyle CssClass="tableRowHighlight" />
    <RowStyle CssClass="odd_tb" />
    <PagerStyle CssClass="foot_tbl" />
    <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="even_tb" />
    <PagerSettings Mode="NextPreviousFirstLast" />
</asp:GridView>
```

pls help me

Comment: what problems are you having?

Comment: Post your 'Submit Button' code

Answer (score 1):

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (gvActList.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (GridViewRow row in gvActList.Rows)
            {
                RadioButton rdYes= (RadioButton)row.FindControl("rdYes");
                RadioButton rdNo = (RadioButton)row.FindControl("rdNo");
                RadioButton rdNone = (RadioButton)row.FindControl("rdNone");
                if (rdYes != null && rdNo != null && rdNone != null)
                {
                    if (rdYes.Checked == true)
                    {
                        //some code
                    }
                    else if (rdNo.Checked == true)
                    {
                        //some code
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

You can use above code on the button click. One suggestion is to use RadiobuttonList instead of RadioButton so that it will reduce the code.

Comment: If you get the solution using above code then please mark it as answer so that it can be useful to other users as well.

Answer (score 0):

on button click declare a gridview row. make a for loop and find the radio button in each row and other controls whose value you want to update. check the conditions as per your requirement and update accordingly